# How to get rid of None while looping through webelements?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, web-scraping

I'm trying to return the list of web elements without any None. Not sure why but seems `pass` doesn't work. Any ideas? please.

BTW. It's possible to fix it by using Pandas but I'd like to stick to pure Python/Selenium and understand what's wrong.

```
def get_(article):
    try:
        article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[div[@class='accessible_elem']]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        title = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[div[@class='accessible_elem']]").get_attribute('aria-label')
        pubdate = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//abbr").get_attribute('data-utime')
        url = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[div[@class='accessible_elem']]").get_attribute('href')
        return(title, pubdate, url)

output = []
for article in articles:
    content = get_(article)
    output.append(content)
```

[image]

Comment: `if title is None: pass`, else ... should work. Notice that an article might exist but have `None` as the values for the attributes you are asking for.

Comment: The critical element is at try: statement. The rest should be executed when True. For sure some articles don't have class='accessible_elem'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue: Your `NoSuchElementException` does not get caught sometimes because there is not a NoSuchElementException thrown.  One example is if an element with class `accessible_elem` exists but does not have the correct attributes you read off.  Also, when you pass due to an exception, the function returns None.

Fix:  It depends, but you probably want to check first if content is None, and then if any of title, pubdate, or url are None before appending. Change your for loop to:

```
for article in articles:
  content = get_(article)
  if content and all([x is not None for x in content]):
    output.append(content)
```

You could shorten the check to:

```
if content and all(content):
```

if you knew that you would never get the value 0 (a falsy value) for any of the tuple values.

Comment: Thank you. Works with minor modification: 

if content is not None:

Comment: Modified to reflect that.  You probably want to return None explicitly from your catch block

Comment: Both pass and return produces None for unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

You used the `try-except-else` structure in an unintended way.

Suggestion using [list comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/):

```py
def analyze_article(article):
    try:
        article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[div[@class='accessible_elem']]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None
    
    # we know that the element must exist if we get to this point
    # if it did not, we returned None already and left the function body
    title = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[div[@class='accessible_elem']]").get_attribute('aria-label')
    pubdate = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//abbr").get_attribute('data-utime')
    url = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[div[@class='accessible_elem']]").get_attribute('href')
    return (title, pubdate, url)


# Get all items, be them None or not
items = [analyze_article(art) for art in articles]

# Filter out all None values
items = [item for item in items if item is not None]
```